# Law of Large Numbers

Tags: self-study, law-of-large-numbers

[image]

How do i proceed with this? any hints would help

Comment: You will get more useful answers if you outline the approaches you have taken so far, or where you are getting stuck.

Comment: @RobertLong i cannot figure out how to begin

Comment: Think about rolling a dice. The expected value is 3.5. If we roll it twice, the mean may be very different from 3.5. If we roll it 10 times it will be closer to 3.5. If we roll is 100 times it will be even closer.  This is the LLN in practice. Apply similar reasoning to the roulette wheel from the point of view of the house and see where that takes you.